# ModalPopupExtender: How do I retain my position after dragging and firing a post back?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I've already tried Google searching for this and looking at the source for this control, but didn't find the answer. If I was able to link into a drag event I would be able to solver this, but I don't think it exists (see this link for a solution with a DragDropPanel (http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=181). How can I do this with the modalPopupExtender? The popup is working well, but after dragging it to a different location, then clicking the Test Partial Postback, the dialog is recentered to its default location.

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelDivPopup" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" style="display:none;" 
    CssClass="modalPopup">
    <img id="modalCancel" class="jqmClose" src="cancel.png" runat="server" enableviewstate="false" />
    <div class="jqmdHeader jqDrag" id="dragHandle">Dialog Title</div>
    <div class="jqmdContent">
        Hello!!
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat='server'>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdatePostBack" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUpdateText" EnableViewState="false" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ID="btnUpdatePostBack" Text="Test Partial Postback" OnClick="btnUpdatePostBack_Click"  />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>          
    </div>
</asp:Panel>    
<ajct:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopupExtender" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
    PopupControlID="panelDivPopup" TargetControlID="linkShowDialog" DropShadow="false"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="modalCancel" 
    Drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="dragHandle" RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll">
    </ajct:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to remove the "DocType" tag or else set the body height e.g inside body add this style="height:1000px" or else add a css class

Comment: I know it's older, but please can you be more specific. I tried your suggestion without any success